# Already defines a member called with the same parameter types

Tags: c#

I'm having 3 errors in my code saying that it has the same parameter types but I couldn't found that kind of same parameters .

Error 1

> Type 'UHFDemo.R2000UartDemo' already defines a member called 'R2000UartDemo' with the same parameter types

Error 2

> Type 'UHFDemo.R2000UartDemo' already defines a member called 'R2000UartDemo_Load' with the same parameter types

Error 3

> Type 'UHFDemo.R2000UartDemo' already defines a member called 'button2_Click' with the same parameter types

I will attach where the errors came

```
public R2000UartDemo()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

//------------------------------------------------
private void R2000UartDemo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//--------------------------------------------------
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Please give me a solution

Comment: If you're using WinForms (if so, please tag it because it might be relevant in this case), have you also checked your `R2000UartDemo.Designer.cs` file? By default, WinForms form classes are split across two [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).

Comment: First delete `button2_Click`, then in the constructor call `button2_Click(null, null)`. Right click on the method call, then press "Go to definition". Where does it bring you?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With the code snippet you provided we will not be able to determine the problem.